# Doing a batch file for first time

Tags: batch-file, path

First time doing batch files, I don't even know how to do it.  I need a batch file that given a path (say `I:\FOLDER1\SUBFOLDER1\`) will produce a text file showing all the subfolders in that directory as fully qualified paths.

Something like this:

```
I:\FOLDER1\SUBFOLDER1\SUBSUBFOLDER1
I:\FOLDER1\SUBFOLDER1\SUBSUBFOLDER2
I:\FOLDER1\SUBFOLDER1\SUBSUBFOLDER3
I:\FOLDER1\SUBFOLDER1\SUBSUBFOLDER4

...
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do. do you want to list the contained subfolders into a text file?

Comment: @1010 Yes exactly. Is it possible? or not?

Comment: `dir /AD I:\FOLDER1\SUBFOLDER1\* > theFile.txt`

Comment: @Aacini I think that won't produce full paths.

Comment: Included information from comments in clarifying the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand you are trying to list file path

```
dir/s/b *.txt
```

to redirect it into a text file

```
dir/s/b *.txt > textfile.txt
```

Help full [Link](http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm)